# Finder window setup in AppleScript - small bug

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm using a handy Finder window set up script (below) from Sal Soghoian's AppleScript 1-2-3 book; works great but if I increase the sidebar width of the second of the two windows that are set up, there is no response to the change - it stays 145; (the first window responds to width changes) comments?

```
tell application "Finder"
close every window
-- first window
open folder "Webclients" of folder "Documents" of home
set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to true
set the sidebar width of the front Finder window to 145
set the current view of the front Finder window to column view
set the bounds of the front Finder window to {16, 80, 550, 675}
-- second window
open folder "Documents" of home
set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to true
set the sidebar width of the front Finder window to 145
set the current view of the front Finder window to column view
set the bounds of front Finder window to {560, 80, 1000, 675}
select the last Finder window
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I found if you increase the width of your second window it will work as expected. For example I used {560, 80, 1500, 675} as the bounds for the second window (notice 1500). At these bounds the sidebar width was correct and changeable. So this must be some effect having to do with the window width and some automatic settings Apple is applying to Finder windows. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First set bound of window then increase width of sidebar.

```
-- second window
open folder "Documents" of home
set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to true
set the bounds of front Finder window to {560, 80, 1000, 675}
set the sidebar width of the front Finder window to 200
set the current view of the front Finder window to column view
select the last Finder window
end tell
```

Finder sidebar width is relative to width of finder window.

```
tell application "Finder"
    get sidebar width of window 1
        --> 136 //maximum value
    get bounds of window 1
        --> {-1, 44, 327, 235}//327-136 =191
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    get sidebar width of window 1
        --> 563 //maximum value
    get bounds of window 1
        --> {-1, 44, 754, 235}//754-563=191
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    get sidebar width of window 1
        --> 843 //maximum value
    get bounds of window 1
        --> {-1, 44, 1034, 235}//1034 -843 =191
end tell
```